# How to wrap Scala Infix expressions within long lines in IntellijIDEA?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, word-wrap, infix-notation, editorconfig

I am using the .editorconfig file in order to configure my IntellijIDEA IDE to reformat Scala code in a specific way.

I specified a right margin, and specified for it not to be exceeded, however, this has a bad impact on long lines that have an Infix expression, which breaks the code.
Everything else is reformatted correctly.

Specific editorconfig configuration :

```
max_line_length = 100
ij_scala_call_parameters_wrap = normal
ij_scala_method_call_chain_wrap = normal
ij_scala_variable_annotation_wrap = normal
ij_scala_wrap_long_lines = true
```

The line i am trying to reformat :

```
  override val fooBarJognDoeLongVar: List[fooBarJognDoeLongVarType] = DoThisDoThat() :: DoThisDoThatAgain() :: DoThisDoThatAgainOneMoreTime() :: DoThisDoThatAgainOneMoreTimeOnceAgain() :: Nil
```

When it's reformatted, it looks like this :

```
  override val fooBarJognDoeLongVar: List[fooBarJognDoeLongVarType] = DoThisDoThat() :: DoThisDoThatAgain() :: DoThisDoThatAgainOneMoreTime() 
  :: DoThisDoThatAgainOneMoreTimeOnceAgain() :: Nil
```

And that breaks the expression apparently. This line should be broken like this :

```
  override val fooBarJognDoeLongVar: List[fooBarJognDoeLongVarType] = DoThisDoThat() :: DoThisDoThatAgain() :: DoThisDoThatAgainOneMoreTime() ::
  DoThisDoThatAgainOneMoreTimeOnceAgain() :: Nil
```

With the `::` kept on the first line, before the line return.

Any ideas on how to do this please ? Of course, using the editorconfig file.

Comment: This question can not be answered because editorconfig simply does not support this. I recommend you switch to scalafmt, IntelliJ has excellent support for that.

Comment: Although i understand editorconfig doesn't specifically support this, the solution doesn't necessarily have to be via editorconfig parameters, it could be a combination, a workaround, Intellij settings, etc ...

Comment: Then the best workaround is to use scalafmt! :)

Comment: That's a long shot, we're a huge team, we can't just do that overnight, especially for such a small issue ... Any other possibilities come to your mind please ?

Comment: Did you already think of shortening the lines manually? Just make sure that the operator is always at the end of a line.

Comment: yes, that's the current workaround, looking for an automated way to perform it (since we're using an editorconfig anyways)